# How can I import bzr branches into git?

Tags: git, bazaar

I am quite used to using git, is there an easy way to import/export from bzr into git and back bzr once I have made commits?

Comment: Since this is not strictly an Ubuntu question, it might be more helpful to ask similar things on StackOverflow in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [git-bzr](http://github.com/kfish/git-bzr). Note the Python rewrites at the bottom of the readme, which may integrate better. Also be advised that there are quite a few forks / derivatives of git-bzr around, but this seems to be most recently active; you may want to look around github for similar things.

Answer (score 5):

[bzr-git](https://launchpad.net/bzr-git) has a "bzr dpush" command that you can use to push a branch into git and a "bzr pull" command that can be used to pull new Git commits into the bzr branch.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions on [Jeff Hodges' blog](http://www.somethingsimilar.com/2008/05/01/moving-from-bzr-to-git-or-tailor-is-so-awesome-i-cream-my-pants/), which uses [tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor) to do the migration.  There's [a list of migration tools available on the bzr website](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrMigration).

Answer (score 1):

You can add and use ["Bridge support in git for mercurial and bazaar"](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/)

> You can clone both mercurial and bazaar repositories now with little to no effort. The original repository will be tracked like any git repository... You can pull, and in fact push as well. Actually, you wouldn’t even notice that this remote is not a git repository. You can create and push new branches... everything.